# C# Polymorphism/Lists

Tags: c#, list, class, object, polymorphism

I've been having trouble with this. I'll summarise briefly.

I have 4 classes. One is a "Person" class. The other three are "Rental", with two classes inheriting from that, "RentalByDay" and "RentalByKM".

Within the "Person" class, there is a list of Rental objects. The issue I'm having is I'm not sure how to add to that list the Rental objects as they are created.

```
class Person
{
    private string _FirstName;
    private string _LastName;

    public Person(string LastName, string FirstName)
    {
        _LastName = LastName;
        _FirstName = FirstName;
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _LastName; }
    }
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _FirstName; }
    }
    public List<Rental> _rentedlist = new List<Rental>();
    public ReadOnlyCollection<Rental> rentedlist
    {
        get { return _rentedlist.AsReadOnly();}
    }  
    public void addrental(Rental Rental)
    {
        _rentedlist.Add(Rental);
    }
    public void PrintRentals()
    {
        foreach (Rental d in _rentedlist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d.Person);
        }
    }
}

class Rental
{

    private double _rentduration;

    Person _Person;

    public double rentduration
    {
        get { return _rentduration; }
        set { _rentduration = value; }
    }

    public Person Person
    {
        get { return _Person; }
        set { _Person = value; }
    }


    public Rental(Person Person, double rentduration)
    {

        _Person = Person;
        _rentduration = rentduration;

    }


}

class RentalByDay : Rental
{

    public RentalByDay(Person Person, double rentbydays)
        : base(Person, rentbydays)
    {

        // add to rental list here?

    }

}

class RentalByKm : Rental
{
    public RentalByKm(Person Person, double rentbykm)
        : base(Person, rentbykm)
    {

        // add to rental list here?




    }

}

class RentalAgency
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Person jane = new Person("Bloggs", "Jane");
        Person joe = new Person("Bloggs", "Joe");
        Person peter = new Person("Piper", "Peter");
        Person penny = new Person("Piper", "Penny");

        new RentalByDay(jane, 5);

        new RentalByDay(jane, 2);
        jane.PrintRentals();

        new RentalByDay(joe, 8);
        new RentalByKm(joe, 15);
        joe.PrintRentals();

        new RentalByDay(peter, 1);
        new RentalByKm(peter, 85);
        peter.PrintRentals();

        new RentalByDay(penny, 5);
        new RentalByKm(penny, 42);
        penny.PrintRentals();

        Console.WriteLine("Quote for {0}", new RentalByDay(null, 10));
        Console.WriteLine("Quote for {0}", new RentalByKm(null, 10));



    }
}
```

The end result should be that when the Printrental is called, that all of the rentals for that person are displayed.

Any help would be appreciated. I feel like this is obvious, but for whatever reason I just cannot figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers, I think i've got it figured out from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the rental, and then add the rental to the user, instead of trying to create the rental, and have the rental itself add itself to a user.

```
jane.addrental(new RentalByDay(jane, 5));
jane.addrental(new RentalByDay(jane, 2));
jane.PrintRentals();

joe.addrental(new RentalByDay(joe, 8));
joe.addrental(new RentalByKm(joe, 15));
joe.PrintRentals();

peter.addrental(new RentalByDay(peter, 1));
peter.addrental(new RentalByKm(peter, 85));
peter.PrintRentals();

penny.addrental(new RentalByDay(penny, 5));
penny.addrental( new RentalByKm(penny, 42));
penny.PrintRentals();
```

You *could* add the rental itself to the person, however, creating objects with `new` and not assigning them to anything is a bit unusual and confusing.

```
public Rental(Person Person, double rentduration)
{
    _Person = Person;
    _rentduration = rentduration;
    _Person.addrental(this);
}
```

You may also want to add a `ToString`override to your `Person` class, so when printed to the console, you get more than just "Person".

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0}, {1} - {2} rentals.", LastName, FirstName, _rentedlist.Count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code

```
   new RentalByDay(penny, 5);
   new RentalByKm(penny, 42);
   penny.PrintRentals();
```

You keep creating new instances of Rental subclasses, and are not associating those instances with the `penny` instance of Person.

You add a reference in your unnamed intance of RentalByKm to penny, but no reference from penny to Penny's rentals.  When you print out the result, you again create a new object instance with no references to any other object.

You need to actually add those unnamed references to penny.

```
   penny.addrental(new RentalByDay(penny, 5));
   penny.addrental(new RentalByKm(penny, 42));
   penny.PrintRentals();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Rental(Person Person, double rentduration)
{

    _Person = Person;
    _rentduration = rentduration;

    Person.addRental(this) // Add this in the base class Constructor. No need to duplicate in each specific

}
```

Comment: This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.

Comment: The comment next to the line added :|

Comment: I don't know their reasoning, man, I just work here ;) (I don't actually work here.)